# How to sort output in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have the following predicate:

```
soln(L,M,O,R,S,V) :-
    permutation([L,M,O,R,S,V],[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    R=\=S+1,
    R=\=S-1,
    M=:=L+1,
    O>M,
    O<S.
```

When I call it from the REPL, it prints out correct answers:

```
?- soln(L,M,O,R,S,V).
L = 1,
M = 2,
O = 3,
R = 4,
S = 6,
V = 5 ;
L = 1,
M = 2,
O = 3,
R = 6,
S = 4,
V = 5 .
```

However, more useful to me would be output where the variables are sorted according to their value; to use the previous example, something like `[L,M,O,R,V,S], [L,M,O,S,V,R], ...` would be ideal.

I would like to be able to do this both in the REPL and in a standalone script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the names according according to their values, you have to keep track of an association between variables and their **names**.

This is because the *variable names* you see in the source code are not accessible within the Prolog program, so you have to keep track of the names in a way that is accessible within Prolog.

One way to do it is to keep track of a list of **pairs** of the form `Variable-Name`. This way, when the variable is bound to a value, you still know its intended *name*.

Therefore, I suggest the following slight rewrite:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solution(Pairs) :-
        Vs = [L,M,O,R,S,_V],
        Names = [l,m,o,r,s,v],
        pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Vs, Names),
        R #\= S+1,
        R #\= S-1,
        M #= L+1,
        O #> M,
        O #< S,
        Vs ins 1..6.
```

Note that I am now using the **atoms** `l`, `m`, `o` etc. to denote the *names* of the variables, and I now reason about **pairs**. Further, I  have taken the liberty to express this all with **constraints**, so we benefit from constraint **propagation** instead of having to try each permutation. Using constraints, the Prolog engine can **prune** a significant portion of the search space without even trying it. I am using `_V` to denote the variable `V`, because this variable is not mentioned anywhere else, and using `V` therefore would result in a singleton warning.

We can already try it out:

```
?- solution(Pairs),
   pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Vs, Names),
   label(Vs).
Pairs = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 1-v],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1],
Names = [l, m, o, r, s, v] ;
Pairs = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 2-v],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2],
Names = [l, m, o, r, s, v] ;
Pairs = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 3-v],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3],
Names = [l, m, o, r, s, v] ;
etc.
```

Now, to **sort** the names according to the values of these variables, use the ISO predicate `keysort/2`, which sorts pairs according to their *keys*, i.e., their first component:

```
?- solution(Pairs0),
   pairs_keys_values(Pairs0, Vs0, Names0),
   label(Vs0),
   keysort(Pairs0, Pairs),
   pairs_values(Pairs, Names).
Pairs0 = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 1-v],
Vs0 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1],
Names0 = [l, m, o, r, s, v],
Pairs = [1-l, 1-r, 1-v, 2-m, 3-o, 4-s],
Names = [l, r, v, m, o, s] ;
Pairs0 = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 2-v],
Vs0 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2],
Names0 = [l, m, o, r, s, v],
Pairs = [1-l, 1-r, 2-m, 2-v, 3-o, 4-s],
Names = [l, r, m, v, o, s] ;
Pairs0 = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 3-v],
Vs0 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3],
Names0 = [l, m, o, r, s, v],
Pairs = [1-l, 1-r, 2-m, 3-o, 3-v, 4-s],
Names = [l, r, m, o, v, s] ;
Pairs0 = [1-l, 2-m, 3-o, 1-r, 4-s, 4-v],
Vs0 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4],
Names0 = [l, m, o, r, s, v],
Pairs = [1-l, 1-r, 2-m, 3-o, 4-s, 4-v],
Names = [l, r, m, o, s, v] ;
etc.
```